# Business Objects JAVA SDK ISessionMgr.logon hangs

Tags: java, crystal-reports, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

We recently upgraded our Business Object XI environment for a new Business Objects 4.1 but we are now experiencing some issues with it

We have an Java web application hosted on a Weblogic server  that use the BO SDK to schedule Crystal Report on another server (Windows VM + tomcat server & BO 4.1)

Here’s the code used for the schedule :

```
  /**
   * Schedule a report inside CrystalReport
   */
  public void executeReport(ReportContext reportContext) throws Exception { 
  logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Executing report request for report '" + reportContext.getReportName() + "'");

  IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = null;
  try {
     String password = getPassword(reportContext);
     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrievieving password ");
     if (password != null) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
           logger.debug("Class CrystalReportHelper, Password obtained '" + password + "'");
        }
        else {
           logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Password obtained ");
        }
     }
     else {
        logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Invalid password for BO Logon");
        throw new Exception("Invalid password for BO Logon - password is null");
     }

     String username = getUserName(reportContext);
     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrievieving username ");
     if (username != null) {
        logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, User name obtained '" + username + "'");
     }
     else {
        logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Invalid username for BO Logon");
        throw new Exception("Invalid username for BO Logon - username is null");
     }

     String cmsName = getCentralManagementServerName();
     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrievieving Central Management Server Name ");
     if (cmsName != null) {
        logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper,Central Management Server Name obtained = " + cmsName);
     }
     else {
        logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Invalid Central Management Server Name for BO Logon.");
        throw new Exception("Invalid Central Management Server Name for BO Logon - Central Management Server Name is null");
     }

     enterpriseSession = getSession(username, password, cmsName);
     if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrieving BusinessObjectEnterprise Session with username'" + username + "' password '" + password + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");
     }
     else {
        logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrieving BusinessObjectEnterprise Session with username'" + username + "' password '" + "XXXX" + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");
     }
     if (enterpriseSession == null) {
        logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Coud not retrieve BusinessObjectEnterprise Session with username'" + username + "' password '" + password + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");
        throw new Exception("Could not retreive BO Session with username : " + username + " and CMS : " + cmsName);
     }
     if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Class CrystalReportHelper, BusinessObjectEnterprise Session retrieve with username'" + username + "' password '" + password + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");
     }
     else {
        logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, BusinessObjectEnterprise Session retrieve with username'" + username + "' password '" + "XXXX" + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");
     }

     IInfoStore infoStore = (IInfoStore) enterpriseSession.getService(cmsName, BO_INFO_STORE);
     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrieving BO service with cmsName'" + cmsName + "' BO_INFO_STORE '" + BO_INFO_STORE + "'");
     if (infoStore == null) {
        logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Coud not obtain BO service with cmsName'" + cmsName + "' BO_INFO_STORE '" + BO_INFO_STORE + "'");
        throw new Exception("Could not obtain BO service : " + BO_INFO_STORE);
     }

     // Queries the CMS for the report.
     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, BO service retrieved with cmsName'" + cmsName + "' BO_INFO_STORE '" + BO_INFO_STORE + "'");

     String queryReport = REPORT_QUERY.replaceFirst(REPLACE_REPORT_NAME, getReportName(reportContext));

     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Executing query report '" + queryReport + "'.");
     IInfoObjects reports = infoStore.query(queryReport);
     if (reports.size() == 0) {
        logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Report '" + queryReport + "' not found..");
        throw new Exception("Report " + getReportName(reportContext) + " not found in BusinessObject");
     }
     IReport report = (IReport) reports.get(0);

     // Set report format.
     IReportFormatOptions reportFormat = report.getReportFormatOptions();

     int formatType = IReportFormatOptions.CeReportFormat.CRYSTAL_REPORT;
     reportFormat.setFormat(formatType);

     String destinationInbox = getDestinationInbox(reportContext);
     IDestinationPlugin destinationPlugin = getDestinationPlugin(infoStore, destinationInbox);

     // Create an interface to the scheduling options for the report.
     ISchedulingInfo scheduleInfo = report.getSchedulingInfo();
     scheduleInfo.setType(CeScheduleType.ONCE);
     scheduleInfo.setRightNow(true);

     IDestination destination = scheduleInfo.getDestination();
     destination.setFromPlugin(destinationPlugin);

     // copy the report parameters
     this.setParameters(reportContext, report);

     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Scheduling report '" + getReportName(reportContext) + "'. ");
     infoStore.schedule(reports);
     logger.info("Class CrystalReportHelper, Report '" + getReportName(reportContext) + "' has been scheduled. ");

     if (reportContext.isEmailRequired() & isEmailEnabled()) {
        sendEmail(reportContext);
     }
  }
  catch (SDKRuntimeException SDKre) {
     logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Could not execute report request for report '" + reportContext.getReportName() + "' caught SDKRuntimeException:  " + SDKre.getMessage(), SDKre);
     throw new Exception(SDKre);
  }
  catch (SDKException SDKe) {
     logger.error("Class CrystalReportHelper, Could not execute report request for report '" + reportContext.getReportName() + "' caught SDKException:  " + SDKe.getMessage(), SDKe);
     throw new Exception(SDKe);
  }
  finally {
     if (null != enterpriseSession) {
        enterpriseSession.logoff();
     }
  }
```

Here’s some data info :

1. `Reportcontext` contains things like user/password for BO, report name and report prompt parameter to use
2. `BO_INFO_STORE = “InfoStore”;`
3. `REPORT_QUERY = "Select * From CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_NAME='" + REPLACE_REPORT_NAME + "' AND SI_INSTANCE = 'false'";`

Here's the method `getSession` used to connect to BO :

```
    /**
     * return BusinessObjectEnterprise session
     *
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @return IEnterpriseSession
     * @throws SDKException
     */
     public IEnterpriseSession getSession(String username, String password,      String cmsName) throws SDKException {
     logger.debug("Class CrystalReportHelper, Retrieving    BusinessObjectEnterprise Session  username'" + username + "' password '" +   password + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");

  IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = null;
  ISessionMgr sessionMgr = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();

  boolean isAuthenticateEnterprise = getReportProperties().getAuthenticationTypeEnterprise();
  logger.debug("Class CrystalReportHelper, isAuthenticateEnterprise  '" + isAuthenticateEnterprise + "' ");
  if (isAuthenticateEnterprise) {
     enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(username, password, cmsName, CeProgID.SEC_ENTERPRISE);
  }
  else {
     enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(username, password, cmsName, CeProgID.SEC_LDAP);
  }

  logger.debug("Class CrystalReportHelper, BusinessObjectEnterprise Session  obtained for username'" + username + "' password '" + password + "' cmsName '" + cmsName + "' ");
  return enterpriseSession;
}
```

The problem we’re experiencing is sometimes the process will hang on this line for about 45min :

```
enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(username, password, cmsName, CeProgID.SEC_ENTERPRISE);
```

Here’s a stacktrace from Weblogic when this occurs :

> ```
> "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" waiting for lock java.lang.Object@3d24ae2c WAITING
>    java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>    java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
>        com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OB.Downcall.waitUntilCompleted(Downcall.java:831)
>        com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OB.GIOPClientWorkerThreaded.receive(GIOPClientWorkerThreaded.java:327)
>        com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OB.GIOPClientWorkerThreaded.sendReceive(GIOPClientWorkerThreaded.java:353)
>    com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OB.Downcall.request(Downcall.java:336)
>    com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.OB.DowncallStub.invoke(DowncallStub.java:583)
>    com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.com.ooc.CORBA.Delegate.invoke(Delegate.java:579)
>        com.crystaldecisions.thirdparty.org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:125)
>        com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.idl.ImplServ._OSCAFactoryStub.newService(_OSCAFactoryStub.java:78)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.i.a(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.i.a(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.i.buildClusterInfo(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.aa.int(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.int(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.p.a(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.ServiceMgr.getManagedService(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.f.if(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
>        com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.SecurityFactory.makeSecuritySession(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.t.a(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.t.userLogon(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.l.userLogon(Unknown Source)
>    com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.b.logon(Unknown Source)
>        com.tranme.guide.commonservices.report.CrystalReportHelper.getSession(CrystalReportHelper.java:156)
>        com.tranme.guide.commonservices.report.CrystalReportHelper.getReportInfoObjectsByReportName(CrystalReportHelper.java:503)
>        com.tranme.guide.notificationmgt.manager.reports.util.ReportManagementTools.getReportInstanceStatuses(ReportManagementTools.java:81)
>        com.tranme.guide.notificationmgt.manager.reports.util.ReportManagementTools.getGenerationStatusResults(ReportManagementTools.java:51)
>        com.tranme.guide.notificationmgt.manager.BaseNotificationManager.updateReportGenerationStatus(BaseNotificationManager.java:244)
>        com.tranme.guide.notificationmgt.business.ejb.impl.NotificationManagementFacadeBeanImpl.updateReportGenerationStatus(NotificationManagementFacadeBeanImpl.java:123)
>         com.tranme.guide.notificationmgt.business.ejb.impl.NotificationManagementFacadeBeanImpl_z3lp9c_EOImpl.updateReportGenerationStatus(NotificationManagementFacadeBeanImpl_z3lp9c_EOImpl.java:140)
>        com.tranme.guide.notificationmgt.business.ejb.impl.NotificationManagementFacadeBeanImpl_z3lp9c_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
>    weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:589)
>    weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
>    weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:477)
>    weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
>    weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
>    weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:473)
>    weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
>    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>    weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
> "Business Objects - Sessions Clean up" TIMED_WAITING
>    java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>    com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.n.run(Unknown Source)
>    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
> "OracleTimeoutPollingThread" TIMED_WAITING
>    java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTimeoutPollingThread.run(OracleTimeoutPollingThread.java:150)
> ```

This never happened before on our BO XI environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Found my own answer.

For people facing the same issue : we have a firewall between the two machines.

When we open a connection between our app and BO, the port is dynamically chosen on the app side.

For now, we disabled the firewall and are looking into a way to set a static port to use on the app side.